# How to read and store data from a text file in which the first line are titles, and the other lines are related data

Tags: java, algorithm, file-io

I have a text file with 300 lines or so. And the format is like:

```
    Name      Amount     Unit    CountOfOrder
      A         1         ml          5000
      B         1         mgm         4500
      C         4         gm          4200

    // more data
```

I need to read the text file line by line because **each line of data should be together** for further processing.

Now I just use string array for each line and access the data by index.

```
for each line in file:
    array[0] = {data from the 'Name' column}
    array[1] = {data from the 'Amount' column}
    array[2] = {data from the 'Unit' column}
    array[3] = {data from the 'CountOfOrder' column}
    ....

    someOtherMethods(array);

    ....
```

However, I realized that if the text file changes its format (e.g. switch two columns, or insert another column), it would break my program (accessing through index might be wrong or even cause exception).

So I would like to use the title as reference to access each column. Maybe HashMap is a good option, but since I have to keep each line of data together, if I build a HashMap for each line, that would be too expensive.

Does anyone have any thought on this? Please help!

Comment: Is there some sort of delimiter which saparates each column data?

Comment: If the format changes, you can use a List to store the name of the columns and use the index to get the field. Otherwise, encapsulate the data in Class.

Comment: @JoshM, sorry I forgot to mention that. Yes, the delimiter is a tab character (\t)

Comment: @D.Q. Are the column headings included in the file?

Comment: @collapsar, hi, this solution is awesome! I was thinking to store data in the map so that I never thought of using number as the value in the map! Can you please make your comment an answer so that I could accept it? Thank you very much!

Comment: @D.Q.: i'm glad that the solution proved helpful and i promoted the comment to an answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need a single hash map to map your column names to the proper column index. you fill the arrays by indexing with integers as you did before, to retrieve a column by name you'd use `array[hashmap.get("Amount")]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file using [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.txt"), '\t');
List<String[]> lines = reader.readAll();
```

The fist line contains the headers.

Comment: I was looking for CSV-answer, but was so disappointed to find all the same "read manually line-by-line"-answers. Thank you for cheering me up :)

Answer (score 0):

you can read each line of the file and assuming that the first line of the file has the column header you can parse that line to get all the names of the columns.

```
String[] column_headers = firstline.split("\t");
```

This will give you the name of all the columns now you just read through splitting on tabs and they will all line up.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            new FileInputStream(FILE)));

    String line = null;
    String[] headers = null;
    String[] data = null;
    Map<String, List<String>> contents = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    if ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        headers = line.split("\t");
    }
    for(String h : headers){
        contents.put(h, new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        data = line.split("\t");
        if(data.length != headers.length){
            throw new Exception();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            contents.get(headers[i]).add(data[i]);

        }
    }
```

It would give you flexibility, and would only require making the map once. You can then get the data lists from the map, so it should be a convenient data structure for the rest of your program to use.

Comment: In you hashMap shouldn't your key should be String[], since header is a String[] array and not String.

Comment: This solution is dynamic, so it will not fail when another column is added. It seems to me it would defeat the whole purpose of using a Map if you were to store the array as the key.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you **individual list of columns**.

```
       public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            List<String> headerList = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> column1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> column2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> column3 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> column4 = new ArrayList<String>();

            int lineCount=0;

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
                try {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    String tokens[];

                    while (line != null) {
                        tokens = line.split("\t");
                        if(lineCount != 0)
                        {
                           int count = 0;
                           column1.add(tokens[count]); ++count;
                           column2.add(tokens[count]); ++count;
                           column3.add(tokens[count]); ++count;
                           column4.add(tokens[count]); ++count;
                           continue;
                         }

                        if(lineCount==0){
                            for(int count=0; count<tokens.length; count++){
                                    headerList.add(tokens[count]);
                                    lineCount++;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    } finally {
                             br.close();
                         }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

using standard `java.util.Scanner`

```
    String aa = "   asd    9    1   3  \n d -1 4 2";
    Scanner ss = new Scanner(aa);
    ss.useDelimiter("\n");
    while ( ss.hasNext()){
        String line = ss.next();
        Scanner fs = new Scanner(line);
     System.out.println(  "1>"+     fs.next()+" " +fs.nextInt() +" " +fs.nextLong()+" " +fs.nextBigDecimal());

    }
```

using a bunch of hashmap's is ok...i won't be afraid ;)
if you need to process a lot of data...then try to translate your problem into a dataprocessing transformation

for example:
  read all of you data into a hashmap's, but store them in a database using some `JPA` implementation....then you can go round'a'round your data ;)\